# the object value comparison to a string value does not happen

Tags: java

```
public class ClientServer {

public static void main (String[] args){

    Object[] selectioValues = {"Server "," Client"};
    String initialSection = "Server";
    Object selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"login As:","Client server", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null , selectioValues , initialSection );

    **if(selection.equals("Server"))**{
        server srv = new server();
        srv.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        srv.startRunning();

    }

   **else if (selection.equals("Client"))**{
        String IPServer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter IP:");
        Client capsa;
        capsa = new Client(IPServer);
        capsa.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        capsa.startRunning();
   }
}

}
```

The code in bold doesn't work. When I added breakpoints to check whether the compiler is going inside IF then it was not. Please explain me why IF condition is not running.

Comment: A compiler doesn't execute your code. `selection` must not be equal to `"Server"`.

Comment: I rechecked my code .selection has the value "Server".and I got no trailing spaces

Answer (score 2):

Your possible selection values are `"Server "` and `" Client"` but you compare to `"Server"` and `"Client"`. The strings are not equal because of the leading/trailing spaces.